# Floating text with more than one line

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've seen vanilla servers that have floating text with multiple lines showing server rules, etc. I read the post where someone explained how to use floating text by using an invisible armor stand with a custom name, but I was wondering how to do it (in vanilla) over multiple lines. Right now I have armor stands a block above one another, but it's very spaced out and hard to see the text at the top. Is there syntax for forcing a new line when entering the custom name? I've tried "\n" and enclosing the text in square brackets and putting each line between double quotes with a comma in between and neither is working for me.

Comment: I'm not sure, but can armour stands be teleported by the half block? If so you could use decimals to make then stand slightly offset from one another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holograms or floating text are created by putting a custom name to a invisible armor stand. If you want to have several lines, you can summon different armor stands.

For vanilla servers: http://www.mctoolbox.me/holograms/

For bukkit/spigot servers: http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/holographic-displays/

Answer (score 1):

\n should work if you have a space after it:

> **{...CustomName:Hi,\n my name is Bob!...}**

[Gamepedia: Formatting Codes](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Formatting_codes)

[Minecraft Json Creator](http://minecraftjson.com)